# Powershell: informations about last Windows graphical copy

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

This is my first post in stackoverflow, so hi to everybody!

I have a strange question. I'm searching for a way to get informations about the last Windows copy with PowerShell (version 3.0). For example, I copy (graphical way, not throw Powershell) one file from one destination to another and than I want to get information about this copy with Powershell (I need only the last copy operation). Exist a way to have this information?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad english!

Federico

Answer (score 0):

This question fits better on SuperUser as you would need to enable file auditing, have a look here:
https://superuser.com/questions/521945/file-auditing-in-windows